# /ect/ansible file is not available in Mac OS

Tags: macos, kubernetes, ansible, minikube

I used pip to install Ansible in MacOS. But I cannot find the `/etc/ansible` folder. Neither the `inventory` file.

I want to run my playbook in `minikube` environment. But the playbook returns,

```
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 192.168.99.105
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using the Virtualbox Hypervisor to run minikube?

Comment: VirtualBox @DawidKruk

Comment: GiHu La please take a look on an answer that I provided below and tell me if it's satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this matter and using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) for managing [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) is not an easy topic. Let me elaborate on that:

The main issue is cited below:

> Most Ansible modules that execute under a POSIX environment **require a Python interpreter on the target host**. Unless configured otherwise, Ansible will attempt to discover a suitable Python interpreter on each target host the first time a Python module is executed for that host.
>   -- [Ansible Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html)

What that means is that most of the modules will be unusable. Even **ping**

#### Steps to reproduce:

- Install Ansible
- Install Virtualbox
- Install minikube
- Start minikube
- SSH into minikube
- Configure Ansible
- Test

#### Install Ansible

As the original poster said it can be installed through pip. 
For example:
`$ pip3 install ansible`

#### Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox)

Please download and install appropriate version for your system.

#### Install minikube

Please follow this site: [Kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/)

#### Start minikube

You can start minikube by invoking command:

`$ minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox`

Parameter `--vm-driver=virtualbox` is important because it will be useful later for connecting to the `minikube`.

Please wait for minikube to successfully deploy on the Virtualbox.

#### SSH into minikube

It is necessary to know the IP address of minikube inside the Virtualbox. 
One way of getting this IP is:

- Open Virtualbox
- Click on the minikube virtual machine for it to show
- Enter **root** for account name. It should not ask for password
- Execute command: `$ ip a | less` and find the address of network interface. It should be in format of **192.168.99.XX**

From terminal that was used to start minikube please run below command:

`$ minikube ssh`

Command above will `ssh` to newly created `minikube` environment and it will store a private key in location: 
`HOME_DIRECTORY .minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa`

`id_rsa` will be needed to connect to the `minikube`

Try to login to `minikube` by invoking command: 
`ssh -i PATH_TO/id_rsa docker@IP_ADDRESS`

If login has happened correctly there should be no issues with Ansible

#### Configure Ansible

For using `ansible-playbook` 2 files will be needed:

- **Hosts**  file with information about hosts
- **Playbook**  file with statements what you require from Ansible to do

Example hosts file:

```
[minikube_env]  
minikube ansible_host=IP_ADDRESS ansible_ssh_private_key_file=./id_rsa

[minikube_env:vars]
ansible_user=docker
ansible_port=22
```

The `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=./id_rsa`  will tell Ansible to use ssh key from file with correct key to this minikube instance. 
**Note that this declaration will need to have `id_rsa` file in the same location as rest of the files.**

Example playbook:

```
- name: Playbook for checking connection between hosts  
  hosts: all  
  gather_facts: no  

  tasks:
  - name: Task to check the connection  
    ping:
```

You can test the connection by invoking command:

`$ ansible-playbook -i hosts_file ping.yaml`

Above command should fail because there is no Python interpreter installed.

> fatal: [minikube]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.99.101 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory\r\n", "msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}

There is a successful connection between Ansible and minikube but there is no Python interpreter to back it up.

There is a way to use Ansible without Python interpreter.

This [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/raw_module.html) is explaining the use of **raw** module.